# Does smart contracts "sync" between Polygon and Ethereum?

Tags: polygon, layer-2

I'm deploying my ERC721 application on the Ethereum network and, of course, fees are a concern. I'm considering giving my customers the option to execute the contract calls on Polygon as well for lower fees, I have a couple questions about it:

1 - Do I have to redeploy the contract on the Polygon network or does it automatically sync with the Ethereum Mainnet after it is deployed?
2 - If I have a limited amount of tokens to be minted, 5000 for example. Do both networks sync so that this limit is applied for both networks and not 5000 for each one?

Sorry if some of these questions are very basic about how these networks interact, Layer 2 is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: They are 2 different blockchains and don’t sync, U can however send data between the networks but it’s hard, take time and probably not worth it

Comment: I think u can do something like this, u need to deploy a contract on ethereum and mint ur nft their, then u need to deploy a special similar contract on polygon and somehow register it on their bridge or somewhere else. After that u need to transfer your nfts to a third contract which lock them, and only then the nft will be minted or able to get minted on polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - Do I have to redeploy the contract on the Polygon network or does it automatically sync with the Ethereum Mainnet after it is deployed?

Polygon and Ethereum are separate blockchains and do not directly communicate.

> 2 - If I have a limited amount of tokens to be minted, 5000 for example. Do both networks sync so that this limit is applied for both networks and not 5000 for each one?

There is no "sync".

[What you need to do is to learn about bridges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQJWMiX4hT0).

Also Polygon is not layer two and any claim saying so is false.

Comment: So essentially Polygon is a glorified BSC?

Comment: In this case "glorified" means that they interact more with Ethereum community and also have high quality projects like Aave and Curve backing them. Unlike BSC that is only copy-pasta shit projects.